# How to get Registarion Id from GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i am developing one application in that i have to send Registration id of GCM from application to my own server i wrote some code its not working please tell me where i made mistake

myAsynTask class

Context context;

```
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";

    String SENDER_ID = "538459826415";

    static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;

    String msg;


    String regid;

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(DetailsDTO... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    httpClient  = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpPost = new HttpPost(TrafficConstants.USER_REG_URL);


    try{
    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
    msg = "Dvice registered, registration ID=" + regid;
    Log.d("111", msg);

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
    arrayList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(=1);

    arrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rigid", regid));

    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(arrayList));
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

LogCat

```
 02-20 15:26:50.915: W/System.err(5400): java.io.IOException: INVALID_SENDER
   02-20 15:26:50.925: W/System.err(5400):  at     
   com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
   02-20 15:26:50.925: W/System.err(5400):  at    
   com.technowellServices.locationfind.async.UserDetailsAsync.doInBackground
    (UserDetailsAsync.j    ava:82)
    02-20 15:26:50.925: W/System.err(5400):     at 

    com.technowellServices.locationfind.async.UserDetailsAsync.doInBackground
   (UserDetailsAsync.j    ava:1)
   02-20 15:26:50.925: W/System.err(5400):  at   
   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    02-20 15:26:50.925: W/System.err(5400):     at   
   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
   02-20 15:26:50.935: W/System.err(5400):  at    
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
   02-20 15:26:50.935: W/System.err(5400):  at   
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
   02-20 15:26:50.935: W/System.err(5400):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: it says you have invalid SENDER_ID. check it

Answer (score 4):

It seems that your sender id it's not correct

> Supply a project name and click Create.
>
> Once the project has been created, a page appears that displays your project ID and project
> number.
>
> For example, Project Number: 670330094152.

You should have in your project page inside the **Google API Console the GCM service activated** and

> Server Application Key 
>  Android Application Key

options generated too.

Then inside **Android Application Key** you should have the hash code and your app packcage name separated by a semicolom.

```
AA:98:0C:AA:03:BD:E7:DA:AA:4A:FA:AF:73:3F:72:E7:D4:11:4S:B1;com.example.myapp
```

The project number it´s the sender id.

Check this out and try again.

Comment: Updated my answer @Durga if you want some more info.